# replace do work in str but does not work in object dtype

Tags: python

```
ab = '1 234'
ab = ab.replace(" ", "")
ab
'1234'
```

its easy to use `replace()` to get rid of the white space, but when I have a column of pandas dataframe;

```
gbpusd['Profit'] = gbpusd['Profit'].replace(" ", "")
gbpusd['Profit'].head()
3     7 000.00
4     6 552.00
11    4 680.00
14    3 250.00
24    1 700.00
Name: Profit, dtype: object
```

But it didnt work, googled many times but no solutions...

> gbpusd['Profit'].sum() TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int")
>   to str

Then, as the whitespace is still here, which cannot do further analysis, like `sum()`
The thing is harder than I think: the raw data is

```
gbpusd.head()
    Ticket      Open Time           Type    Volume  Item    Price   S / L   T / P   Close Time              Price.1 Commission  Taxes   Swap    Profit
84  50204109.0  2019.10.24 09:56:32 buy     0.5     gbpusd  1.29148 0.0     0.0     2019.10.24 09:57:48     1.29179 0           0.0     0.0     15.5
85  50205025.0  2019.10.24 10:10:13 buy     0.5     gbpusd  1.29328 0.0     0.0     2019.10.24 15:57:02     1.29181 0           0.0     0.0     -73.5
86  50207371.0  2019.10.24 10:34:10 buy     0.5     gbpusd  1.29236 0.0     0.0     2019.10.24 15:57:18     1.29197 0           0.0     0.0     -19.5
87  50207747.0  2019.10.24 10:40:32 buy     0.5     gbpusd  1.29151 0.0     0.0     2019.10.24 15:57:24     1.29223 0           0.0     0.0     36
88  50212252.0  2019.10.24 11:47:14 buy     1.5     gbpusd  1.28894 0.0     0.0     2019.10.24 15:57:12     1.29181 0           0.0     0.0     430.5
```

when I did

```
gbpusd['Profit'] = gbpusd['Profit'].str.replace(" ", "")
gbpusd['Profit']
84          NaN
85          NaN
86          NaN
87          NaN
88          NaN
89          NaN
90          NaN
91          NaN
92          NaN
93          NaN
94          NaN
95          NaN
96          NaN
97          NaN
98          NaN
99          NaN
100         NaN
101         NaN
102         NaN
103         NaN
104         NaN
105         NaN
106         NaN
107         NaN
108         NaN
109         NaN
110         NaN
111         NaN
112         NaN
113         NaN
         ...   
117     4680.00
118         NaN
119         NaN
120         NaN
121         NaN
122         NaN
123         NaN
124         NaN
125         NaN
126         NaN
127         NaN
128         NaN
129         NaN
130    -2279.00
131    -2217.00
132    -2037.00
133    -5379.00
134    -1620.00
135    -7154.00
136    -4160.00
137     1144.00
138         NaN
139         NaN
140         NaN
141    -1920.00
142     7000.00
143     3250.00
144         NaN
145     1700.00
146         NaN
Name: Profit, Length: 63, dtype: object
```

The white space is replaced, but some data which has no space is NaN now...someone may have the same problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

also need to use `str`

```
gbpusdprofit = gbpusd['Profit'].str.replace(" ", "")
```

Output:

```
0    7000.00
1    6552.00
2    4680.00
3    3250.00
4    1700.00
Name: Profit, dtype: object
```

and for sum:

```
gbpusd['Profit'].str.replace(" ", "").astype('float').sum()
```

Result:

```
23182.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I met a new problem; can you also help, I think other may also has this problem

Comment: NaN writes for null values. and still, you can sum or convert the profit. what exception do you get?

Comment: I dont have exception, the numbers dont have white space, are also NaN. But it should numbers

Comment: Some of the profit cells data types are not string. You need to convert all to string before replacing. You can add this before the replace `gbpusd['Profit'] = gbpusd['Profit'].astype(str)`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to string and sum in a oneliner:

```
gbpusd['Profit'].str.replace(' ', "").astype(float).sum()
```